# Python pickle.load throws __init___ error

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, pickle, init

In python 3.3 I have written some code which attempts to pickle an instance of a user-defined class. The pickling seems to go well but on unpickling I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\Python Programs\Conway's Game Of Life\GameOfLife.py",                 
line 172, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\Python Programs\Conway's Game Of Life\GameOfLife.py", 
line 156, in main
    newGrid = browseSaves()
  File "C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\Python Programs\Conway's Game Of Life\GameOfLife.py", 
line 71, in browseSaves
    return loadGrid(choice)
  File "C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\Python Programs\Conway's Game Of Life\GameOfLife.py", 
line 64, in loadGrid
    g = pickle.load(f)
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 4 positional arguments (5 given)
```

I was under the impression the __ init __ was not called on unpickling. I have no clue as to what is causing this error. Any help is appreciated and any questions will be answered.

The class I am trying to pickle, the grid class, can be found here: http://pastebin.com/LQwsvJkh

Update: I have tried adding some filler arguments to the grid class' init, but the error still says "4 arguments". It may not refer to that class' init.

Comment: It would help if we saw the class of the pickled instance.

Comment: The entirety of it can be found here: http://pastebin.com/LQwsvJkh (I'm trying to pickle the "grid" class, the "tile" class was included because of how they are linked.)

Comment: Please add it to the question with an edit, rather than linking to it.

Comment: Does your class have a [`__getinitargs__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getinitargs__)?

Comment: I don't have a __getinitargs__ method, and I didn't want to throw all 190 lines in to the main question.

Comment: Can you include the full traceback in the question? It sounds like the exception may be coming from somewhere other than your `Grid` class. For instance, you might have trouble with the `surface` object that the object contains (in my brief and probably incomplete tests, `Surface` objects from PyGame can be pickled without an immediate error, but they're useless when they're unpickled).

Comment: Full traceback is now included.